# Remove tracked file from Merge Request that was deleted using Gitlab Web Editor

Tags: git, gitlab

I accidentally committed a file that wasn't supposed to be in the MR. Then, using the web editor of Gitlab, I removed the file.

Now it shows up in the changes as 'file deleted' but I don't want the file change to be there at all. I currently have a lot more commits piled on top since the file removal.

How can I make sure that I can remove the deleted file from appearing in the MR changes at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to make a new commit that restores the file to what it was before your changes. Let's say the file is `myFile.txt`, and the commit where you made your first change to it is `123abc`. Do the following:

```
git checkout 123abc~ myFile.txt
git commit -am "Restoring myFile.txt"
```